# trying to create simple Slide show method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create a basic JavaScript snipped to slide images forward and back on a webpage when links are clicked.

Here is my js code in the `<head>` section of the webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   //if browser does noe support getElementbyId then exit
   var step = 1;
   if ( !document.getElementById ) {
       return;
   }
   var src = 'images/gallery_images/image'+step+'.jpg';
   document.getElementById('photos').src = src;

   function slideForward()
   {
        //files are named as image1, image2....
        step++;
        var src = 'images/gallery_images/image'+step+'.jpg';
        document.getElementById('photos').src = src;
   }

   function slideBack()
   {
       step--;
       var src = 'images/gallery_images/image'+step'.jpg';
       document.getElementById('photos').src = src;
   }
</script>
```

I bind the 2 functions for moving backwards using `onclick` in a tag like:

```
<a onclick="slideBack()">
    <img src="images/gallery_06.jpg" alt="" name="left" width="26" height="90" id="gallery_06" />
</a>
<a onclick="slideForward()">
    <img src="images/gallery_07.jpg" alt="" name="right" width="27" height="90" id="gallery_07" />
</a>
```

Any suggestions on what I am missing? Nothing is being returned.

Comment: you are missing a plus here `function slideBack()
{
    step--;
    document.getElementById('photos').src= 'images/gallery_images/image'+step+'.jpg';
}`

Comment: nopes the function slideBack() is for sliding back the image so for instance if the current displayed image is "image3.jpg", slideBack() is to display "image2.jpg" .

Comment: FOCUS: `'images/gallery_images/image'+step HERE '.jpg';`

Comment: You're missing the bits that wrap around the extent of the gallery—when you're at the last image, *slideForward* should go to the first, and when you're at the first, *slideBack* should go to the last.