# Make a looping JavaScript Slideshow without jQuery

Tags: javascript, slideshow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trying to create simple Slide show method in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263458/trying-to-create-simple-slide-show-method-in-javascript)

I have learn to make carousel image slideshow script with JavaScript. I think it's better to learn it from the basic than we just make something from the framework (instant script) but I'm a newbie. I write this script using my technique, but I think it's terrible.

OK, here is my question :
I don't know how to make this slideshow loop, anyone can help me?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
        width:400px;
        height:140px;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        margin: -70px 0 0 -200px;
        background: #383838;
        overflow: hidden;
        }

        #abc-container {
        position: absolute;
        width:1200px;
        height:140px;
        }

        #a {
        width:400px;
        height:140px;
        background: #FF0000;
        float: left;
        }

        #b {
        width:400px;
        height:140px;
        background: #FFFF00;
        float: left;
        }

        #c {
        width:400px;
        height:140px;
        background: #00FFFF;
        float: left;    
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="abc-container">
            <div id="a"></div>
            <div id="b"></div>
            <div id="c"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="asas"></div>
    <div id="asass"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var runCarousel, runTimer;
        firstval = 0;
        secondval = 0;

        function Carousel(){
        firstval += 10;
        document.getElementById('abc-container').style.left = "-" + firstval + "px";
        document.getElementById('asas').innerHTML = "-" + firstval;
            if(firstval == 400)
            {
                StopRun();
                StartTimer()
                return;
            }
            if(firstval == 800)
            {
                StopRun();
                StartTimer()
                return;
            }
        runCarousel = setTimeout(Carousel, 10);
        }

        function StartTimer(){
        secondval += 1;
        document.getElementById('asass').innerHTML = "-" + secondval;
        if(secondval == 10)
        {
            StopTimer();
            Carousel();
            return;
        }
        if(secondval == 20)
        {
            StopTimer();
            Carousel();
            return;
        }
        runTimer = setTimeout(StartTimer, 1000);
        }

        function StopRun(){
        window.clearTimeout(runCarousel);
        }

        function StopTimer(){
        window.clearTimeout(runTimer);
        }

        function firstStart(){
            setTimeout("Carousel()", 10000);
        }

        firstStart();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider posting a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar; that way we can see what's going on. And we don't have to make our own demos: help *us* to help *you*.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly there is an error:

```
function firstStart(){
     setTimeout("Carousel()", 10000);
}
```

correctly:

```
function firstStart(){
     setTimeout(Carousel, 10000);
}
```

in the end, all settings are reset to default and start timer:

in Carousel:

```
if(firstval == 1200){
        document.getElementById('abc-container').style.left = "0" + "px";
        firstval = 0;
        StopRun();
        StartTimer()
        return;
    }
```

in StartTimer

```
if(secondval == 30) {
        secondval = 0;
        StopTimer();
        Carousel();
        return;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M8GhH/)

[Here is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/M8GhH/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your response :). but the loop don't look smooth as I wish. The first part (red) just back without animation.

Comment: @user1697962 look at this http://jsfiddle.net/M8GhH/2/

Comment: Hi great idea to make it loop like that, but I've found my way how to make it loop. Thanks for your help, I advice it :)